# How to make any sed, awk, and grep command ignore lines beginning with #?

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

I have a script containing a wide variety of `sed`, `awk`, and `grep` commands, the only similarity is that they each receive an input file, edit it, then send it to an output file. Here are some basic examples:

```
sed "/^word$/d" input.txt > output.txt
grep "word" input.txt > output.txt
awk 'sub(/.*{/,"")' RS='}' input.txt > output.txt
```

I need to edit all of the scripts, such that they will always ignore any lines that are commented out by placing a `#` at the start of the line. Is there a single solution, e.g. using pipe, to get any kind of `sed`, `awk`, and `grep` to ignore such commented lines, or do I need to use some in-built features in each of these to get them to ignore commented-out lines?

How can I make any `sed`, `awk`, and `grep` command ignore lines beginning with #?

Comment: I don't really get what you are asking. `sed` and `awk` are perfectly suitable to do these kind of hings, but it really depends on what your script looks like now.

Comment: An example might help.  Your questions often seem to lack an example.

Comment: I get what you're asking: some global notation with the semantics of transmitting a transformation to individual text operations, without it having to appear individually in those transformations.

Answer (score 3):

You can make following changes to your script to ignore `#` lines:

#### For `sed`: (The following would ignore anyways since you have anchored `word`)

```
sed "/^#/!{/^word$/d}" input.txt > output.txt
```

#### For `grep`:

```
grep -v '^#' input.txt | grep "word" > output.txt
```

**or**

as suggested by [@devnull](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2235132/devnull) in the comments, if your `grep` supports the `-P` option then you can do:

```
grep -P '^(?!#).*word' input.txt > output.txt
```

which is a negative lookahead telling `grep` that pick words that do not have `#` anchored at the beginning of the line.

#### For `awk`:

```
awk '!/^#/{sub(/.*{/,"")}' RS='}' input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: +1.  But I'd avoid a pipeline in case of `grep`.  If `grep` supports PCRE, you could use `'^(?!#).*word'` instead.

Comment: @devnull Ah! yes, the negative lookahead. Good point! Will add that to the answer. Thanks `:)`.

Answer (score 2):

Put `grep -v '^#' file |` in front of each command.

Answer (score 1):

You can come close with Bash process substitution, which can use functions in your scripts, not only external commands:

```
#!/bin/bash

strip_comments()
{
   sed -e '/^#.*/d' "$1" 
}

# like grep "$1" "$2", but on comment-stripped "$2"
grep "$1" <(strip_comments "$2")

# ... other commands that use <(strip_comments ...)
```

Of course, grep cannot report the original locations in the original file. Ideally we would want some kind of macro language to hide this stuff.

To make the syntax look like

grep pattern input

we would need macro-preprocessing: something which recognizes the symbol `input`, and macro-substitutes in the `<(whatever ...)` syntax.

If you just put that into a variable and then use $variable, that won't work; however, it will if `eval` is used. With `eval`, you have to then escape things against the double evaluation; it's not pretty.

```
input='<(strip_comments input.txt)'  # quoted: this is like a symbol macro

# ...

eval grep '$pattern' $input
```

(Given that the original Bourne shell was developed by a man who began the program with `#include <algol.h>`, a header full of macros for making C look like Algol, it's ironic that the macro capability isn't there.)

Comment: In `/^#.*/d`, the `.*` adds no value.

Comment: @EdMorton By golly, you are right. I think that was initially supposed to be an edit that strips comments to the end of line, when I realized that commented out lines are to be stripped.